# What is the proper JSDOC syntax for referencing imported es6 classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsdoc, commonjs

I'm trying to figure out proper syntax for specifying external classes as params/returns in JSDOC.

so, for example, I have:

```
import redux from 'redux';

/**
 * @param {object} state
 * @return {{module:redux.Store}}
 */
export function initState(state=initialState) {
  store = redux.createStore(theReducer, Immutable.fromJS(state));
  return store;
}
```

the problem is, that if I use this in webstorm, "Go To Declaration" on `Store` sends me to totally irrelevant place.

which means, that either my syntax is wrong (what is the right one?) or it is a bug in Webstorm

Answer (score 1):

syntax looks ok... Logged as [WEB-19261](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19261), please follow it for updates